# Having trouble calling a method from a class

Tags: java, class, methods, compiler-errors

I'm trying to finish my project by calling the methods I've created in my class. I'm getting an error "constructor in class cannot be applied to given types.

Here is my main

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[] grades = {98.7, 77.9, 90, 83, 67, 33, 81, 90 };
    HomeworkGrades cls = new HomeworkGrades();
```

and this is my class

```
public class HomeworkGrades {
    private double[] grades;
    double [] HWgrades = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};

    public HomeworkGrades(double [] gradesEarned)
    {
        grades= gradesEarned;  
        for (int i =0; i<gradesEarned.length;i++)
            HWgrades =gradesEarned;
    }
     public double calcAverage()
    {
        int sum =0;
        for(int i =0; i<HWgrades.length; i++)
        {
            sum = (int) (sum + HWgrades[i]);
        }
        double average = sum / (double)HWgrades.length;
        return average;
    }
     public static  double calcLowestGrade(double[]a, double total)
     {
         double temp;
         double size;
         double  array[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
         size = array.length;
         for (int i =0; i <size; i++)
         {
             for(int j=i+1;j<size;j++)
             {
                 if(array[i]>array[j])
                 {
                     temp=array[i];
                     array[i] = array[j];
                     array[j] = temp;
                 }
             }
         }
         System.out.println("Lowest grade is " + array[0]);
         return array[0];
     }    
}
```

Comment: Your `HomeworkGrades` constructor takes a `double[]` as a parameter, but you aren't passing your `grades` array as an argument.

Comment: `HomeworkGrades cls = new HomeworkGrades(grades );` ?

Comment: That fixed the error! But now when I run the project it just says build successful without printing the average and lowest grade of the array in main

Answer (score 2):

The constructor you shared takes a `double[]`. It seems like you forgot to pass the `grades` array you created:

```
double[] grades = {98.7, 77.9, 90, 83, 67, 33, 81, 90 };
HomeworkGrades cls = new HomeworkGrades(grades);
```

Comment: Uf... you were slightly faster I guess ^^

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to set the parameter for your `new HomeworkGrades()`-instance.

Therefore

```java
double[] grades = {98.7, 77.9, 90, 83, 67, 33, 81, 90 };
HomeworkGrades cls = new HomeworkGrades();
```

should be

```java
double[] grades = {98.7, 77.9, 90, 83, 67, 33, 81, 90 };
HomeworkGrades cls = new HomeworkGrades(grades);
```

Besides... You are doing some crazy stuff while initializing HomeworkGrades...

This will work just fine:

```
    double[] HWgrades;

    public HomeworkGrades(double [] gradesEarned) {
        HWgrades =gradesEarned;
    }
```

You aren't even using `private double[] grades;` and you don't have to set your array array.length times in order to get the array at the end. Just do it once.

**EDIT**
In order to print your Average or whatever you want from the instance just get the double and print it in System.out.println()

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] grades = {98.7, 77.9, 90, 83, 67, 33, 81, 90};
        HomeworkGrades cls = new HomeworkGrades(grades);
        System.out.println("Average: " + cls.calcAverage());
    }
```

**EDIT2**
Your function to get the lowest grade is strange... Just use this istead:

```java
    public double calcLowestGrade() {
        double lowest = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        for (double d : HWgrades) {
            if (d < lowest) {
                lowest = d;
            }
        }
        return lowest;
    }
```

One mistake was that you made the function static and therefore it couldn't get the HWgrades array. Furthermore you don't have to create a new array because you already gave the object the array in the beginning.

Comment: Okay now in main how do I get it to print the actual results from my method? I've tried system.out.println(); with cls and grades in the ()

Comment: I added this to my answer. But basically it's just `System.out.println("Average: " + cls.calcAverage());`

Comment: Oh okay that should've been obvious lol, that one works but when I try to call on my calclowestgrade method i'm getting an error "method in class cannot be applied to given data types. required double[], double. I tried taking out the [] in this line { public double calcLowestGrade(double[] a, double total)}

Comment: And edited one more time... If it helped you please upvote my comment and mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: Yeah I was having trouble with that method, yours works though, thanks so much!